# What's going on with this space between my images? PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, image

So, currently i'm programming my own website. The design is way not finished yet, so don't blame me for that xD Well, I've got a very small problem with a gap which is not supposed to be where it is (red square in the picture below). Do you know how it comes/came there?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Red Square!]
My Code:
(the while loop is there the pictures are displayed)

JustBasti's website

Home

```
    <a href='index.php?mod=news'>News</a>
    <a href='index.php?mod=allnews'>All News</a>
    <a href='index.php?mod=gallery'>Gallery</a>
    <a href='index.php?mod=guestbook'>Guestbook</a>
    <a href='index.php?mod=admin'>Administrator</a><table>
<tr>

    <td>Nam liber tempor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Saturday, 11th Jun 2011, 7:00 pm</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/aus.png' rel='lightbox[testalbum]'
        title='aus.png'><img src='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/thumbs/aus.png' /> </a>

    </td>
            <td><a href='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/airport.png' rel='lightbox[testalbum]'
        title='airport.png'><img src='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/thumbs/airport.png' /> </a>
    </td>
            <td><a href='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/fam.png' rel='lightbox[testalbum]'
        title='fam.png'><img src='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/thumbs/fam.png' /> </a>
    </td>
            <td><a href='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/way.png' rel='lightbox[testalbum]'
        title='way.png'><img src='albums/110611190045 - Nam liber tempor/thumbs/way.png' /> </a>
    </td>

        </tr>
```

```
while ($photos = mysql_fetch_array($photo)){
    $url_thumb = $photos['url_thumb'];
    $url = $photos['url'];
    $title = $photos['title'];
    ?>
    <td><a href='<? echo $url; ?>' rel='lightbox[testalbum]'
        title='<? echo $title; ?>'><img src='<? echo $url_thumb; ?>' /> </a>
    </td>
    <?
}
```

The website is not online yet. I didnt use any CSS. I just coded in php and html.

Comment: You need to show the final, generated HTML, not the PHP source in this case

Comment: HTML and CSS please... not PHP.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your query - we would need to see the markup and styles you're using.

Comment: HTML *is* allowed by the way (not that that was HTML, but yea).

Comment: Look at how your table is constructed. The first column is using a shared width in the rows above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `colspan=3` or so (or as long as the table goes) for your first 3 rows:

- the navigation bar
- the latin quote
- and the date

Personally I wouldn't even put them in the table, but that's me. Anyway your problem stems from the 3 rows I mentioned being stuck in a cell and forcing the width of the first column to be bigger than the image.

Comment: yea, you're right. I just noticed that the gap is reaching exactly to the end if the date displayed. Thanks :) Also a thanks to the other dudes who tried to help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time problems like this depends on spaces in HTML. Try to delete all the spaces of you code, such as:

```
<a> </a> --> <a></a>
```

And you'll see the spaces will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox, try plugin Firebug and right-click on the empty space, choose "edit", on its left panel it will show you all margins, paddings etc.
\If using Chrome, you dont need to install anything as by default similar addon its already there.
Eventually another great plugin for FF is WebDeveloper, in its menu go for "select">"select element" and click on your empty space.

Also you should use:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">Nam liber tempor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">Saturday, 11th Jun 2011, 7:00 pm</td>
</tr>
```

if you haven't got it in your CSS already